# How to draw in web 2.0?

Tags: html, drawing

I heard that drawing abilities will be supported by Web 2.0

Tried to find something in Internet about, nothing really clear. Could you please point me into something that allows (or will allow in future) to draw in HTML?

For example: I want to have ability draw few hexagons in different color on the page.

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry if question is a little bit "stupid", but I can't make it more smart.

Comment: Re “stupid” —  not at all, your question is very clear. The reference to “Web 2.0” makes it sound a bit newbie, as that’s a vague marketing term with no specific meaning. In the context of drawing in HTML, it’s HTML5 that supports it. Nothing wrong with having it in the question though, as other people might have made the same association, so they can find answers here via Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick exemple of what you want to do:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hexagon canvas tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(){
        //first let's get canvas HTML Element to draw something on it
        var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
        //then let's see if the browser supports canvas element
        if (canvas.getContext){
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            //Pick Hexagon color, this one will be blue
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
            //let's start a path
            ctx.beginPath();
            //move cursor to position x=10 and y=60, and move it around to create an hexagon
            ctx.moveTo(10,60);
            ctx.lineTo(40,100);
            ctx.lineTo(80,100);
            ctx.lineTo(110,60);
            ctx.lineTo(80,20);
            ctx.lineTo(40,20);
            //fill it and you got your first Hexagon
            ctx.fill();

            //This one will be green, but we will draw it like the first one
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(110,160);
            ctx.lineTo(140,200);
            ctx.lineTo(180,200);
            ctx.lineTo(210,160);
            ctx.lineTo(180,120);
            ctx.lineTo(140,120);
            ctx.fill();
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick example. If we go further and try to change hexagon color? Guess, we could catch "OnMouseOver" for canvas and if mouse cursor is inside of required hexagon... we need either redraw the same coordinates with another color... Or .. Is it possible to get already drawn object and just change its color?

Comment: HTML5 canvas is interpreted as an image, so attaching events to his elements can be really tricky. I will have a look at this tomorrow an give you feedback if I find anything.

Comment: I am very appreciate your help! Waiting for ideas! Thanks!

Comment: I did some investigation and I didn't find any way to attach events to the drawn elements, neither make changes to the canvas elements without redrawing them. Basically if you want to change the hexagon color you have to clear canvas and redraw it with a new fill color.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about is most likely the HTML5 [Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, but links seems broken

Comment: @Budda: really? works fine for me. But I see you've got the help you needed anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've been hearing about the Canvas Element.  You can get started with it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element

Good luck!